# Remote TFS Checkin via Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

We currently have a Scheduled Task on each local PC that runs the command "TF.exe /checkin" when triggered remotely using schtasks. this is so that when someone forgets to check-in we have a way to do so remotely.

But we would like to integrate this into a PowerShell script that can be triggered remotely by just entering the computer name but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work.

This runs fine on the local pc

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe' checkin /recursive}
```

However, when adding -ComputerName it fails to work with the following error.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName *ComputerName* -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe' check-in /recursive}
```

> Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjetCollectionURL'.
> +CategoryInfo: NotSpecified (Unable to deter...ColletionUrl'.:string [], Remoteexpection

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've already tried /collection:https://tfsserver:port/collectionanme but it doesn't work either

Error: Option /collection cannot be used without option /shelveset which is weird as I am not using /shelveset.

-----Update----

See the image below, before running the powershell script, I had a file checked out on my local pc, then running Enter-PSSession to a remote computer and then running invoke-command still only checked in my local files and not on remote computer.
[image]
[image]

---update 04/12---

I don't know why it doesn't work same issue "unable to determine the workspace"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify workspace path on remote session with the following code:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Set-Location D:\workspace}
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
```

[image]

Then run tf command:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe' checkin /recursive}
```

Entire result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, but when I tried it, it only checked in my files and not the one on the remote PC :D

Comment: When you run `$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Set-Location D:\workspace}
Enter-PSSession -Session $session`, are you able to see it returns the remote machine path? I've added the screenshots for your reference.

Comment: I've updated the OT, please have a look at the issue. Yes if I run the above code, I do see the remote computer as `[ComputerName]: PS C:\U_C>` then when I run `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe' checkin /recursive}` I get the same 'Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjetCollectionURL'. +CategoryInfo: NotSpecified (Unable to deter...ColletionUrl'.:string [], Remoteexpection'

Comment: You need to run `$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Set-Location D:\workspace}
Enter-PSSession -Session $session` first, when it returns `[ComputerName]: PS C:\U_C>`, run `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock`.

Comment: And make sure the remote session is either using the user the workspace belongs to or that the workspace is set tu be a public workspace. Otherwise, `tf.exe` won't be able to find the workspace for the user that initiated the remote session in that machine.

Comment: all our workspaces are public, also running it exactly as suggested doesn't work. check the OT updated image added

Comment: Is `C:\U_C` on computer `BayVL00-022` a valid workspace? Is the workspace owner the same as the account your ran the powershell? You may create a new workspace on computer `BayVL00-022`, and navigate to this new woekspace to try again.